# What's difference between factory, producer and provider, regarding responsibilities, life-cycle of objects and DI dependencies?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, naming-conventions

I've seen terms `SomeProducer`, `SomeProvider`, and `SomeFactory`, used as class names pretty much randomly in some projects.

I have not yet seen clear definition of responsibility for DI Beans for names mentioned above. Often, `SomeFactory` depended on `OtherService`, or `OtherConnector`. The actual implementation and naming depended on developer.

Reason for this question: I would like to write clean, and nicely readable and understandable, code. To free others of pain caused by reading and understanding of spaghetti code.

Comment: The naming has not to depend on one developer. Naming conventions for very specific thing is often something that the team has to decide with its members,  sometimes this even is a company decision. Pair programming and code review allow to find acceptable conventions fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal perspective, I think there is a *hierarchical relationship*
The `Provider` provides a service such as Object-relational mapping where we use for example `HibernatePersistenceProvider` to tell the container that we are going to use Hibernate as an implementation of JPA
At the same time, we create `EntityManagerFactory` to manage all entity managers created from it then the `Producer`  comes to create  managed objects so that CDI can discover them.

Answer (score 0):

**`Provider`** in Java is associated with dependency injection: see [jakarta.inject.Provider](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/dependency-injection/2.0/apidocs/jakarta/inject/provider). As such a `Provider` may be wrapping some `Factory` or constructor invocation to adapt it to `jakrata.inject` API, or may be decorating another `Provider` with a logic of deciding which `Scope` to check for an existing instance before producing a new one (`Scope` definition is framework specific, see for example the one from [Guice](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/7.0.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Scope.html)).
Given the above, you rather shouldn't be naming your classes `SomethingProvider` unless you are developing or extending some DI framework. It is however common and appropriate to name your params/vars `somethingProvider` when they are in fact declared with such type (directly or transitively through class/interface hierarchy).

**`Factory`** is not specific to DI, but is a  [classic OO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). It is  supposed to return a new instance each time and hide details  which specific subclass/implementation of `Something` is being used.
`Factory` pattern is utilized in many places across core Java, see for example [EntityManagerFactory](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/entitymanagerfactory).
`Factory` is also sometimes used to keep common configuration for objects that are being created: see for example [ThreadFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) that can be used to create `Threads` sharing for example a common `ThreadGroup` or a priority. However when using DI, such config data should rather be bound using annotations (like [@Named](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/dependency-injection/2.0/apidocs/jakarta/inject/named)).

**`Producer` AFAIK** in Java jargon is usually just a synonym for `Factory`.

Assuming I'm not wrong about `Producer` being just a synonym for `Factory`, `SomethingFactory` is a more classic, better recognized term and I would favor it over `SomethingProducer` as a class name in most cases. IMO `producer` should rather be used in a context of some [producer-consumer synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) as a param or a var name.